# Using VPS server when I create directory using mkdir() it returns true but folder when I check using cpanel is blank,

Tags: php, mkdir, scandir

Using VPS server when I create directory using mkdir() it returns true but folder when I check using cpanel is blank, I dont know why I even used scandir() and I noticed that those folders which I created is showing in an array in scandir(), why is that happening, why those folders are not showing ?
This is my code:

/**creating directory**/

```
                if (!file_exists('public_html/members/1213121')) {
                    mkdir('public_html/members/1213121', 0777, true);
                    echo "file getting created";
                }
                else{
                    echo "file not getting created.";
                }

                /**this is the code I put to scan the members folder and it retuns array and showing the folder named 1213121 but in actual cpanel that directory is not there **/

                $dir = "public_html/members/";

                // Sort in ascending order - this is default
                $a = scandir($dir);

                // Sort in descending order
                $b = scandir($dir,1);

                print_r($b);
```

since I did the testing with other folder names also so it returns in html as below::
file getting created
Array ( [0] => 1213121 [1] => 12131 [2] => 1213 [3] => .. [4] => . )

Also I did the testing with permissions as 0755, 0700 but none is working.

Comment: what does error reporting throw back? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: That is the thing , it is not showing any error, it is returning true and directories are being created according to php code it is going to if statement not else... but those folders are not there in members directory when I used cpanel. I am using  error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); in my file and none of the error is being returned.

Comment: "it is returning true"  Where exactly are you _checking_ that? Not in the code above. Entering the `if` shown above simply means that the given file/directory doesn't exist, not that anything was (or wasn't) created.

Comment: When I am using scandir(), it is returning those foldernames in an array  and plus there is no error so what should that mean.. Am I right? what should I do if I am wrong can  you please tell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your server folder permission is ok then this code is work for you.
this first script for deleting the '1213121' folder from your server.
script 1:

```
delete_files('/public_html/members/1213121/');

/* 
 * php delete function that deals with directories recursively
 */
function delete_files($target) {
    if(is_dir($target)){
        $files = glob( $target . '*', GLOB_MARK ); //GLOB_MARK adds a slash to directories returned

        foreach( $files as $file ){
            delete_files( $file );      
        }

        rmdir( $target );
    } elseif(is_file($target)) {
        unlink( $target );  
    }
}
?>
```

replace your script with this script 2:

```
$dir = 'public_html/members/1213121';

if (!file_exists($dir) && !is_dir($dir)) { //check dir is not exist

    if (mkdir($dir, 0777, true)) { //check folder is created
        echo "Folder created"; //display success message
    } else {
        echo "folder not created."; //if the dir is not created then show error message
    }
}

/**this is the code I put to scan the members folder and it retuns array and showing the folder named 1213121 but in actual cpanel that directory is not there **/

$dir = "public_html/members/";

// Sort in ascending order - this is default
$a = scandir($dir);

// Sort in descending order
$b = scandir($dir, 1);

print_r($b);
```

**Note: before replacing 2nd script you must remove e first script.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved actually the file which is creating the folder is in the subdomain and when I put the exact path , it was not pointing to it instead it created new public_html folder in subdomain and I was in main public_html.. it created a path like:-public_html/subdomainfolder/public_html/members/1213121 and instead i was thinking that path will be created as public_html/members/1213121 ... So my problem is solved now and Mahfuz answer is also right. thanks for the help.